# Rails 2 create method and saving parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, save, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm upgrading a Rails 1 app to 2.3, and I'm running into a problem with a code block like the following:

```
@foo = Foo.new(...)

params[:baz].each do |b|
  @foo.bars.create(...)
end

...

@foo.save
```

This worked fine in Rails 1. After the upgrade, invoking this `create` method yields:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved in BazController#create :
You cannot call create unless the parent is saved
```

How did the `create` method change between Rails 1 and 2, and what's the proper way to handle this now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@foo.bars.build` instead of `create`